# If two Wi-Fi access points share the same BSSID, does it mean that they work on the same channel?

Tags: ieee-802.11

It is my understanding that if an ESSID is used by several sets of APs on several channels (let's say one AP = one channel only), then two APs sharing a BSSID should also share their radio configuration, including the channel, allowing for a partition of the clients over BSSIDs/channels. But my understanding of this kind of setup is limited and it would be great if someone could either confirm or explain my mistake.

Comment: No, the radios are independent, and it is common to set adjacent WAPs to different channels, power levels, etc.

Comment: @RonMaupin OK, what is the distinction then between two APs with same ESSID and BSSID, and two APs with same ESSID but different BSSIDs?

Comment: Or maybe my misunderstanding is deeper, and two APs in an infrastructure should never have the same BSSID. I can't find the source anymore of how I got this idea, so I might just have misread an article about having several BSSIDs on the same AP.